# PHP: Array entry not set even though dump shows it is present

Tags: php, arrays, isset

I have a problem where an entry in a "keyed" array is considered unset, even though a dump of the array clearly shows it is present. This is run with PHP 8.0.19 (cli).

The code:

```
private static function processRow( array $row ) : void {
    if ( ! isset( $row[ 'id' ] ) ) {
        Logger::log( "Row 'id' is not set: "  .  var_export( $row, true ) );
        return;
    }
}
```

...and the resulting output:

```
[05-Jun-2022 19:52:01 UTC] Row 'id' is not set: array (
  '﻿id' => '2',
  'type' => 'page',
  'title' => 'Home Improvement Financing',
)
```

I don't understand why this condition is true. It must be simple, but I can't see it.

Comment: I'd also would have the same problem I must admit. Perhaps a non-printable character? Perhaps further process the string with [`addcslashes()`](https://php.net/addcslashes) for some of them (`\0..\x1F\x7F` ) for starters.

Comment: @hakre, wouldn't that have shown up in the var_export dump? It's supposed to be the source code required to recreate the data. I did delete and replace the 'id' in the conditional to rule out that possibility.

Comment: well could be, but I'm not sure like always. As strings in PHP are binary, there technically is no necessity to specifically encode control characters for var_dump. compare: https://3v4l.org/9doD5 /E: err update: https://3v4l.org/JLRk8 - only for very old versions

Comment: If not the non-printable ones, it's perhaps a printable one. E.g. some Unicode that looks as if. Maybe hex-dump array_keys().

Comment: No, but yeah, no idea actually. I would not convert the encoding, but instead first of all debug which keys the array actually has as isset($row['id']) returns false but the output suggests it is there. maybe `var_export(key($row), true)` to highlight the first key.

Comment: @hakre, I'll be dipped...you were right, there was an unprintable character right before 'id', converting it to ascii yielded '?id'. Thank you!

Comment: Well, `isset()` was right, I was just guessing^^

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the data. The key of the first array row, the one that looks like 'id', actually had an unprintable character at the beginning of the string, and so "isset()" was indeed correct.

I corrected this by running the data through `mb_convert_encoding( $row, 'ASCII', 'UTF-8' )`, and then used `str_replace()` to remove the question marks. In my case, that was acceptable, but it wouldn't be for most.